# UE4 Try Get Pawn Owner Node Location

Tags: unreal-4

Where is the Try Get Pawn Owner node located in BP? I can't find it anywhere. I'm following the answer [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/298098/accessed-none-callfunc-getplayercharacter-returnva-1.html) but cannot find this node anywhere. Using version 4.11.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so to make this node appear you have to uncheck the Context Sensitive box top right of the search field:

[image]